# PHP bool Expression

Tags: php, booleano

Estou trabalhando em uma expressão booleana configurada pelo usuário da aplicação. Essa expressão vem da base de dados logo é uma string, eu preciso fazer o PHP entende-la para eu ter o true e false.

Exemplo :

```
Expressao_string = ”(1 and ( 0 or 1) )”;
```

Como esse valor da string vem de uma base, preciso fazer essa string ser valida para o PHP.

Comment: No banco de dados está como `tinyint(1)`?

Comment: Se ela está vindo por 1 e 0, acredito que você não precise fazer nada. Trate o 0 como false e o 1 como true.

Comment: Quais as operações lógicas que serão consideradas? Apenas *and* e *or* ou também o *not*, *xor*, etc?